# Bootstrap tooltip positioning is unexpected in responsive viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, responsive

Hi Stack overflow community

I am using a bootstrap tooltip with some text and image inside. In desktop view, it is working as expected but when I am looking into a responsive/mobile view, when a user is clicking on the tooltip icon it's coming right in the center (overlapping the content). I want to be displayed either to top or bottom based on the available space.

[image: Issue Screenshot]

Expected:
[image]

Code:

```
<label for="lotnumber" class="form-label label-error">Lot Number</label>
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="tooltip-main" data-html="true" title="<p>What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><p class='text-center'><img src='images/lot-screenshot.png'/></p>">
<i class="fa fa-question-circle icon-tooltip"></i>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-error" placeholder="" id="p_lot_number">
```